Occasional IllegalStateException in Android mediaPlayer.prepare or mediaPlayer.setDataSource
I contribute to an open source Android app for mobile data collection. One of the things it can do is autoplay audio prompts for questions. We are recently seeing crashes from forms that have many audio prompts. Users report that these crashes are unpredictable and can't be reproduced.
We see IllegalStateExceptions thrown from Android's MediaPlayer.setDataSource or MediaPlayer.prepare(). There is no exception message.
reset is always called before those two calls:
mediaPlayer.reset()
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri)
mediaPlayer.prepare()

Full source.
The code above is called off the UI thread. Looking at Android source, I can't see where IllegalStateException would be thrown from. The only possible issue I can think of is some kind of concurrency problem. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this or reproduce it?
